# How can I Split the String Correctly?

Tags: java, string, split

I am getting a result of `"kjhvkjkasdfkjh@grouping@group_group.12018-08-20"`.

I am looking to split the string in java to only get the `"2018-08-20"`.

Any suggestions? The part I want is always at the end.

Comment: If you are sure that the part you want is always at the end and always an iso date with 10 character why split at all and not just use substring?

Comment: Do you maybe have a suggestion?

Comment: I just wrote my suggestion, use substring to get the last 10 characters of your string

Comment: You could also find the first period in your string and then take whatever comes after it (assuming the format is similar to all responses)

Comment: Please post your attempted code?

Comment: `string = string.substring(string.length() - 10);`

Answer (score 1):

```
String sample = "kjhvkjkasdfkjh@grouping@group_group.12018-08-20"
int SubstringStart = sample.length() - 10;
String outputsample = sample.substring(SubstringStart);
```

will break if string has length shorter than 10

Comment: I got it, thank you! :D